# Прочитать файл из /res/raw

Tags: android

нужно прочитать .mp4 из /res/raw в приложение и поместить в file. 
Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Беглое гугленье намекает на то, что вам проще будет в `assets` папку файл поместить. Так будет гораздо проще. В `res` стоит держать только `xml` или картинки.

Comment: Ещё можете вот это посмотреть - там проигрывание `mp3` из ресурсов. Если это вам и надо - ОК. Однако лучше в `assets` поместить. https://acadgild.com/blog/load-mp3-resource-raw-folder